# Run a program as a domain user if the machine isn't on the domain?

Tags: windows-7

Say you have a domain: `SomeDomain`.  And a domain user, `SomeUser`.  Can you run an application in the context of `SomeDomain\SomeUser` even if the machine you are running on **isn't** part of the domain, and the currently logged in user to the non-domain machine is a local account?

**EDIT**

What I want to do is run SQL Server Management Studio as a domain user so that it authenticates against the server as a domain user.  The machine that SSMS will run on is a non-domain machine and the user is local account.  Is this possible?

Comment: You will run the SQL Server Management Studio as your normal local user. However, once the software is loaded, you will need to connect to the SQL Server which will ask for an authenticated user on that domain/SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no good reason to do this. The `SomeDomain\SomeUser` would not be authenticated on that local machine. Even if SomeUser was an administrator/domain admin on SomeDomain, it would still not do any good on the local machine. If it would, that would be huge security holes with Windows and allow me to bring a laptop with my own domain controller on it and then access someone's computer on that same network (ie, coffee house).

In order for SomeUser to do anything on that local machine, you would have to have local admin rights to that machine to join it to the domain. From there you would be able to use SomeUser to perform whatever necessary actions.

## [Edit]

Ah. That is not really the same. When you open up the SQL Management Studio, it will ask you what server you want to connect to. This is basically asking you for authentication of a user who has access to that SQL Server. In this scenario, different from your original question, would be able to select the Server that you wish to connect to, valid user who has access to the SQL Server and password. You're accessing a network resource that is part of the domain and will need to authenticate with a user who has access to the resource on that domain. In your scenario, this will work.

Comment: Check out my edit, maybe that explains it a little better.

Comment: Check out my edit, :)